# TEMPLATE - GET PARAMETER LIST

Tags: python, django

```
 class ParametroProducto(models.Model):
    parametros_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    tipo_parametro = models.CharField(max_length = 80)


 class FamiliaProducto(models.Model):
    nombre_familia = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    parametro_familia = models.ManyToManyField(ParametroProducto)


 class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    proveedores = models.ManyToManyField(Proveedor, null=True, blank=True)
    familia = models.ForeignKey(FamiliaProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Recepcion_Envase_Insumo(models.Model):
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deposito = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=30)
    fecha = models.DateField(null=False,default=date.today)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    observaciones = models.TextField()

 class ControlEnvIns(models.Model):
    envase_insumo = models.ForeignKey(Recepcion_Envase_Insumo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parametro_env_ins = models.ForeignKey(ParametroProducto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resultados = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

---

Forms.py

```
  class FormEnvIns(forms.ModelForm):
    
        proveedor= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Proveedor.objects.filter(activo=True),
        widget=forms.Select(),required=True)
    
    
        producto=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.filter(activo=True),
        widget=forms.Select(),label='Insumo')
    
        responsable=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Empleado.objects.filter(activo=True),
        widget=forms.Select())
    
    
    
        class Meta:
            model = Recepcion_Envase_Insumo
            
            fields = [
            'fecha',
                'proveedor',
                'responsable',
                'cantidad',
                'deposito',
                'producto',
                'observaciones',
            ]
            
            labels = {
                'fecha':'Fecha de recepcion',
                'proveedor':'Proveedor',
                'responsable' : 'Responsable',
                'cantidad':'Cantidad recibida',
                'deposito':'Deposito',
                'producto':'MP',
            }
    
            widgets = {
                'fecha':forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
                'cantidad':forms.NumberInput(),
                'deposito':forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'}),
                'observaciones':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 3}),
                
            }
    
    
    
     class FControlEnvIns(forms.ModelForm):
        
        parametro_env_ins=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ParametroProducto.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(),label='Parametros')
    
        class Meta:
            model = ControlEnvIns  
    
            fields = [
                'parametro_env_ins',
                'observacion', 
                'resultados',
                ]
            
            labels = {
                'observacion':'Observacion',
                'resultados':'Resultado ',
            }
    
    
            widgets = {
                'observacion':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                'resultados':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                
            }
```

---

View.py

```
  def registro_envase_insumo(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        recepcion_form = FormEnvIns(request.POST)
        detalle_form = FControlEnvIns(request.POST)

        if recepcion_form.is_valid() and detalle_form.is_valid():
            envase_insumo  = recepcion_form.save(commit=False)

            producto_seleccionado = envase_insumo.producto

            parametros = producto_seleccionado.familia.parametro_familia.all()

            envase_insumo =  recepcion_form.save()      

            for parametro in parametros:
                envase_insumo_det = detalle_form.save(commit=False)
                envase_insumo_det.envase_insumo = envase_insumo
                envase_insumo_det.parametro_env_ins = parametro
                envase_insumo_det.save()
            

            messages.success(request,("Registrado Exitosamente"))
            return redirect('listar_recepcion') 
        else:

            messages.error(request,("Error, Verifique los campos"))
            for field_name, errors in envase_insumo.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    messages.error(request,f"Error en el campo {envase_insumo.fields[field_name].label} : {error}")
    else:
        recepcion_form = FormEnvIns()
        detalle_form = FControlEnvIns()

    return render(request, 'recepcion/envase_insumo_conj.html',{'env_ins_form': recepcion_form,'env_ins_det_form': detalle_form})
```

How to obtain the list of parameters in the template by selecting the product in the 'FormEnvIns' form in the product field, and then obtain the list of parameters and display it in the FControlEnvIns form in the `parametro_env_ins` field.

This is my view and I don't know if I'm on the right track.
What I realize is that I must use javascript but I don't know how I could do that part
The *FControlEnvIns* form and the *FormEnvIns* form must appear only in a template.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. There is no JavaScript in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need, is to send a request to your backend retrieve the data you want, and update the DOM element. And, as you mentioned JS is used to achieve this.

A new view that does not render a page, instead just return the data you need:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Producto
import json


def registro_envase_insumo_product_params(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    product = Producto.objects.get(pk=data['productId'])
    params = list(product.familia.parametro_familia.all().values())
    return JsonResponse(params, safe=False)
```

On the frontend. Add an event listener to the `product select box`, send the request to your backend, clear the `param select box` and repopulate it with new data. It is also necessary to [attach `csrf` token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) to the request headers.

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    ...
}

const productSelectElement = document.getElementById('id_producto');
const paramsSelectElement = document.getElementById('id_parametro_env_ins');

productSelectElement.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/insumo/product/params';
    const body = JSON.stringify({ productId: productSelectElement.value });

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken },
            body: body
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        for (let i = paramsSelectElement.options.length; i >= 1; i--) {
            paramsSelectElement.remove(i);
        };

        data.forEach(param => {
            let opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = param.id;
            opt.innerHTML = param.parametros_producto;
            paramsSelectElement.appendChild(opt);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong.')
    }
});
```

Following the comment, you can [`annotate with F expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) by accessing the related fields:

```py
params = list(
    product.familia.parametro_familia
    .prefetch_related('controlenvins')
    .annotate(
        resultados=F('controlenvins__resultados'), 
        observacion=F('controlenvins__observacion'))
    .values()
)
```

Comment: It's worked !!.
But how can add rest of field with the list of parameters.
For each parameter I need to add field observacion and resultado field, and then save.
These fields are displayed in the form:
class FControlEnvIns(forms.ModelForm):

Comment: You can either repeat the process and send another request to fetch the data you want or use the first view to gather it all at once in a more complex way. In terms of best practice you want the second choice, since its always better to avoid unnecessary requests to your server to avoid overload. (I will append an example to my answer)